# How to localize password emails and password change form?

Tags: control-panel, localization, password

Just wrapping up my first multi-language Craft 2.x site, and the last localization issue we're having is the password reset process. I can't find a way to localize:

1. The email which is triggered by the "forgot password" form.
2. The language which the user will be see to when clicking the email's "reset" link.

There are some inconsistencies here because when I have my user set to, for example, Canadian French as their preferred locale, the subject of the email is localized, but the body is not (naturally, since there's no place to actually translate the body text anywhere that I can find), and when the link is visited, the form is in English (even though the link resides in my `/fr/` directory, where the config file sets my local to  `fr_ca`, and the user in question has `fr_ca` as their preferred locale).

Is there a solution here?

Comment: Bump? Maybe Craft 3 solves this with sites replacing locales?